# WPF DataBinding Very Slow when I use Convert to format a date

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, converters, ivalueconverter

I'm writing a simple app to display some data on a DataGrid.  The data is just a measurement (float) and a timestamp.  The timestamp a uint and is in seconds since 2000.

I sucessfully accomplished the task but did notice it takes a long time (~1 minute) to display the datagrid.  There are about 20,000 data. I wouldn't think 20,000 datum consisting of a uint and a float was that mush. The next request was to display the time as formatted time instead of seconds since 2000.  This I did by making the XAML look like this:

```
<kit:DataGridTextColumn Header="FilteredValue" Binding="{Binding Path=FilteredValue}" />
<kit:DataGridTextColumn Header="Timestamp" Binding="{Binding Path=Timestamp, Converter={StaticResource TimeConverter}}" CanUserSort="False" />
```

The TimeConverter method looks like:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    DateTime currentDateTime = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    currentDateTime = currentDateTime.AddSeconds((uint)value);
    return currentDateTime.ToString();                  
}
```

This also worked fine.  However, it turns out that some of the raw data can be 0xFFFFFFFF.
This means that there is no data or invalid data.  In this case, I don't want to convert to a date.  So I wrote:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{

    if ((uint)value == 0xFFFFFFFF)
    {
    // don't bother to convert
    return ((uint)value).ToString("X");
    }
   else
   {
    DateTime currentDateTime = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    currentDateTime = currentDateTime.AddSeconds((uint)value);
    return currentDateTime.ToString();
   }

}
```

Again, it works, but it's very **slow**.  Slower than the original and takes about 10 minutes.  I was pretty amazed by this.  Is it just the case that the extra code is running 23,000 times? 
1.  What should I be doing?  Can I do something in XAML so my Converter is not called if not necessary?
2.  When I have 0xFFFFFFFF for one of the measurements (FilteredValues) it gets displayed as NaN.  This is probably ok, but it would be nice just to show 0xFFFFFFFF or "no data".  I think it's getting set to NaN because the underlying data type is a float.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Dave

Here is the XAML.  The last Datagrid is the one of interest.  Note that I even set "IsVirtualizing" to True".  Also note the use of ScrollViewer.  I did this because otherwise I can't see all the rows on the last grid (when it finally) displays.  Removing this did not speed things up.

```
<Window x:Class="STDatabaseReader.Window1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:chartingToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit" xmlns:kit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:STDatabaseReader"
    Title="Smart Transmitter Database Reader">
<Window.Resources>

    <local:BytesToStringConverter x:Key="BytesToStringConverter"></local:BytesToStringConverter>
    <local:TimeConverter x:Key="TimeConverter"></local:TimeConverter>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
     <ScrollViewer>    
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <Button Name="m_btnFetchData" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="m_btnFetchData_Click">Fetch File</Button>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center">Partition 1</Label>
                    <kit:DataGrid Name="m_gridPartion1" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                        <kit:DataGrid.Columns>
                            <kit:DataGridTextColumn Header="Header Info" Binding="{Binding Path=HeaderInfo, Converter={StaticResource BytesToStringConverter}}" CanUserSort="False" />
                            <kit:DataGridTextColumn Header="Transmitter Id" Binding="{Binding Path=TransmitterId, Converter={StaticResource BytesToStringConverter}}" CanUserSort="False" />
                            <kit:DataGridTextColumn Header="DeviceNumber" Binding="{Binding Path=DeviceNumber}" />
                            <kit:DataGridTextColumn Header="HardwareVersion" Binding="{Binding Path=HardwareVersion}" />
                            <kit:DataGridTextColumn Header="CRC" Binding="{Binding Path=CRC}" />
                        </kit:DataGrid.Columns>
                    </kit:DataGrid>
                </StackPanel>

                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center">Partition 3</Label>
                    <kit:DataGrid Name="m_gridPartion3" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                        <kit:DataGrid.Columns>
                            <kit:DataGridTextColumn Header="Header Info" Binding="{Binding Path=HeaderInfo, Converter={StaticResource BytesToStringConverter}}" CanUserSort="False" />
                            <kit:DataGridTextColumn Header="SystemTime" Binding="{Binding Path=SystemTime, Converter={StaticResource TimeConverter}}" />
                        </kit:DataGrid.Columns>
                    </kit:DataGrid>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center">Partition 2</Label>
                <kit:DataGrid Name="m_gridPartion2" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                    <kit:DataGrid.Columns>
                        <kit:DataGridTextColumn Header="Header Info" Binding="{Binding Path=HeaderInfo, Converter={StaticResource BytesToStringConverter}}" CanUserSort="False" />

                        <kit:DataGridTextColumn Header="FirmwareRevision" Binding="{Binding Path=FirmwareRevision, Converter={StaticResource BytesToStringConverter}}" CanUserSort="False" />

                        <kit:DataGridTextColumn Header="SoftwarePartNumber" Binding="{Binding Path=SoftwarePartNumber, Converter={StaticResource BytesToStringConverter}}" CanUserSort="False" />

                        <kit:DataGridTextColumn Header="FirmwareUpgradeTime" Binding="{Binding Path=FirmwareUpgradeTime,Converter={StaticResource TimeConverter}}" />
                        <kit:DataGridTextColumn Header="DatabaseEraseTime" Binding="{Binding Path=DatabaseEraseTime,Converter={StaticResource TimeConverter}}" />
                        <kit:DataGridTextColumn Header="RangeEnzymeElectrode" Binding="{Binding Path=RangeEnzymeElectrode}" />
                        <kit:DataGridTextColumn Header="OffsetEnzymeElectrode" Binding="{Binding Path=OffsetEnzymeElectrode}" />
                        <kit:DataGridTextColumn Header="BiasValue" Binding="{Binding Path=BiasValue}" />
                    </kit:DataGrid.Columns>
                </kit:DataGrid>
            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center">Partition 4 - HeaderInfo</Label>
                    <kit:DataGrid Name="m_gridDataHeader" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                        <kit:DataGrid.Columns>
                            <kit:DataGridTextColumn Header="Header Info" Binding="{Binding Path=HeaderInfo, Converter={StaticResource BytesToStringConverter}}" CanUserSort="False" />
                        </kit:DataGrid.Columns>
                    </kit:DataGrid>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel   Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center">Partition 4 - Chemistry Data</Label>

                        <kit:DataGrid Name="m_gridData" AutoGenerateColumns="False" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"  Loaded="m_gridData_Loaded">
                            <kit:DataGrid.Columns>
                                <!--
                                <kit:DataGridTextColumn Header="Noise" Binding="{Binding Path=Noise, StringFormat=\{0:X8\}}" />
                                <kit:DataGridTextColumn Header="FilteredValue" Binding="{Binding Path=FilteredValue, StringFormat='X'}" />
                                 <kit:DataGridTextColumn Header="Timestamp" Binding="{Binding Path=Timestamp, StringFormat=\{0:X\}}" />   -->
                            <kit:DataGridTextColumn Header="Noise" Binding="{Binding Path=Noise}" />
                            <kit:DataGridTextColumn Header="FilteredValue" Binding="{Binding Path=FilteredValue}" />
                            <kit:DataGridTextColumn Header="Timestamp" Binding="{Binding Path=Timestamp, Converter={StaticResource TimeConverter}}" CanUserSort="False" />
                        </kit:DataGrid.Columns>
                        </kit:DataGrid>

                </StackPanel >
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
     </ScrollViewer>     
</Grid>
```

Comment: would a profiler help you see the bottleneck here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the column is a `DataGridTextColumn` you can make it display 0xFFFFFFFF by just returning it in the converter

```
if ((uint)value == 0xFFFFFFFF)
{
    // don't bother to convert
    return "0xFFFFFFFF";
}
```

As for the `DataGrid` being slow, it should be using a `VirtualizingStackPanel` by default so if you haven't changed this then it should be pretty fast since you'll only be working with the `DataGridRows` that are visible to the user at the moment. Also the code in the converter should take virtually no time.

So the most likely reason for your `DataGrid` being slow is probably that you've changed the `ItemsPanel` to something else than a `VirtualizingStackPanel` or disabled the virtualization somehow but it's hard to tell without seeing how your `DataGrid` is defined

**Edit**
Run the following code after your `DataGrid` has finished loading, for example in the `Loaded` event for the `DataGrid`. If the `MessageBox` displays a large number (shouldn't be above 50) then you have the source of your problem.

```
private void DataGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;
    List<DataGridRow> generatedDataGridRows = VisualTreeHelpers.GetVisualChildCollection<DataGridRow>(dataGrid);
    MessageBox.Show(generatedDataGridRows.Count.ToString());
}
public static List<T> GetVisualChildCollection<T>(object parent) where T : Visual
{
    List<T> visualCollection = new List<T>();
    GetVisualChildCollection(parent as DependencyObject, visualCollection);
    return visualCollection;
}
private static void GetVisualChildCollection<T>(DependencyObject parent, List<T> visualCollection) where T : Visual
{
    int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
        if (child is T)
        {
            visualCollection.Add(child as T);
        }
        else if (child != null)
        {
            GetVisualChildCollection(child, visualCollection);
        }
    }
}
```

---

For example, using a `StackPanel` as the parent panel will be very slow since the `DataGrid` can consume unlimited vertical space so all the rows will be generated

```
<StackPanel>
    <!-- Slow DataGrid with 20000+ items in ItemsSource -->
    <DataGrid ...>
</StackPanel>
```

but using a `Grid` will be very fast because the `DataGrid` will be restricted in height so Virtualization can be used

```
<Grid>
    <!-- Fast DataGrid with 20000+ items in ItemsSource -->
    <DataGrid ...>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks Meleak, I tried some of your suggestions.  I put the XAML in my original post.  It's the last DataGrid that has the 20000+ items.  I tried throwing some <Grid> around the <DataGrid> to no avail.  It's still slow.  I do make extensive use of StackPanels but I'm assumming you are referring to the immediate Parent Panel?  I also tried your code to see what the count of rows is.  It comes up with '0' when I first launch the app, and then the code is never hit when I fetch the file.  Is there another event other than 'Loaded' I need to look at?  Many Thanks, Dave

Comment: @Dave: Name the `DataGrid` to something, e.g. dataGrid (in case you haven't done this already) and once the `DataGrid` is Loaded and you can see the data, just add a `Button` and execute that code in the `Button` click event. Let me know the result

Comment: Meleak, I added the button handler and got a count of 13080 so this seems like the problem, but where am I going wrong?  Does anything look wrong with the datagrid named m_gridData in the above XAML?  As I said, my code is full of StackPanels but I wouldn't thik the use of stackpanel (to organize content) is incompatible with DataGrids.  Thanks, Dave

Comment: @Dave: The problem is the `StackPanels`. A `StackPanel` always gives its children the space they ask for. So if you add a `Grid` inside a `StackPanel` and a `DataGrid` inside the `Grid`, the `DataGrid` will tell the `Grid` how much it wants and then the `Grid` will tell the `StackPanel` what it wants and the `StackPanel` gives it the full Height, in your case 13080 rows. Using a `Grid` with `RowDefinition Height="Auto"` will get you the same result, try to use '*' sized Grid-RowDefinitions for it. Start out with just the datagrid with 20000+ rows and work your way back

Comment: Meleak,  Thank you very much for all your help.  Duly marked as answer.   I didn't quite follow your last response as to thingso to try, but I certainly understood the part about  Grid telling StackPanel that it wants height for 13080 rows.  So I changed DataGrid to: <kit:DataGrid Height="400"  This is a hack, because I didn't understand your comments about RowDefinition Height="Auto" Is this suppose to go in the Grid definition?  And what did you mean by "use '*' sized Grid-RowDefinitions for it?  Anyhow, I tried, but w/o success.  Possibly, because I didn't understand.Thanks again.

Comment: @Dave. Yes, Height="400" can certainly solve it :) And yes, you're on the right track. Specify the Rows for a `Grid` like `<Grid><Grid.RowDefinitions><RowDefinition Height="*"/>` and then specify which row you want to put an element in by e.g. <DataGrid Grid.Row="1".. /> etc. See this for an example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.row.aspx. Good luck!